# How to obtain a current page data to imitate a Reply message in discussions?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, buddypress

I want to add a special widget (e.g. in the start message) which will be have a Submit button. The user interacts with widget, then presses this button and the widget should add a result as a reply message.

The reply form sends a post request with some parameters. Where can I grab it?
[image]

Maybe there is a some plugin with such a feature?

Comment: Looks like a sort of contact form. Give a try to CF7: https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/

Comment: Thanks. But as I understand this a pure WP-plugin and therefore it don't require these "special" parameters on submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these props as hidden form fields. I don't know how I missed them at first.

[image: Hidden parameters]

For feeds the similar information is stored in a global variable `BP_Nouveau`.

```
console.log(BP_Nouveau.activity.params);
```